# How to get the size of a single character in a (web) font?

Tags: python, fonts, svg, font-size

I write a python script in order to generate a SVG file. This SVG file uses a web font ( imported from google webfonts via CSS ) to render my texts nicely. Everything is fine except I need to know the size (in pixel) of a sentence before putting it in my SVG file.

As I started learning python few days ago, I don't know if this kind of stuff is possible. Google helped me to find the existence of the ImageFont python module (from the Python Imaging Library) but it seems ImageFont needs to load font file from a local path in order to compute character size.

Is there any chance a way to compute character size on a web font exists ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to know the size of your sentences ? Is it about text wrapping ?

Comment: Actually I have paths I use as textPath. I have a word to repeat on this path until I reach the end of it. For example if my word is foo i'll have "foo" repeated as much as it can be written on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it on the client side with javascript and the SVG DOM.

First step : create a text element and compute its length with the getComputedTextLength() method ( http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement )

```
<text id="foo" xml:space="preserve">foo </text>
```

Then compute the path length with the getTotalLength() method ( http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement )

And you can compute how many times you can put your text before it is truncated.

Comment: After reading your answer (good answer btw) I understood my problem was not exactly a problem. Actually, I use CSS to change style easily during development and test few things, but when I asked about my web font question I forgot one of the main needs I have with my script : the exported SVG HAS TO BE readable by Gimp / Inkscape / Illustrator. Clearly it's not possible with CSS, so webfonts won't be an option (or maybe I'm wrong on that one too). Then I'll go with both local and web font to perform my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be using the same font every time? If so: grab a local copy of the font, run your tests locally, and cache them (SQLite database? Array of widths stored in a Python module? That part's up to you). However, be warned, that the width of a sentence is likely not the same as sum of the width of its characters due to [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). If you want to be accurate, you'll need to calculate the width of the sentence itself.

Does this really need to be done on the server, though? If your client is a web browser, for example, you could use something like jQuery's [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method to ask the browser the actual size of the element, or [do some manipulation in your own JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732292/svg-text-font-with-fixed-width-height).

Even better might be to design your SVG with a more "liquid" layout and the expectation that the element might grow or shrink to an arbitrary size, and use plain dumb code like `elementtext = elementtext[:100]` to limit its length to some predetermined threshold value. Basically, make sure it works for up to a certain amount of text, then ensure you won't be using more than that much text. You're not using the Declaration of Independence as a text label, right?

Comment: First aff all, thank you for that quick answer. In fact, I may use several different fonts. Kerning is a real problem, but it only depends of the solution I use. Thanks to SVG kerning is not a BIG problem as long as I can set I manually (I guess I read something about that in the SVG documentation). Anyway, I plan to write long sentences, not the Declaration of Independence, but long enough to invalid the elementtext[:100] I think (I have to test that anyway). Concerning the use of Javascript on client side, it is an acceptable answer but as I told to @Tangui that part of my question is wrong.